# Prevent word from breaking when there is image in the middle of word

Tags: html, css

According to the web page design, there is an image used instead of "O" letter (sometimes). 
The problem: when window is resized, sometimes part of word after image is going to new line
Desired behavior: whole word should go to new line if it is not fitting.
Yes I can wrap these words with `<span>` tag with css rule `white-space: nowrap` but it is not a desirable solution because client wants to be able to edit this in Wordpress visual editor.
Any ideas on how to prevent word with image inside from breaking?
https://jsfiddle.net/jas1rmwx/ - resize the window to see the problem.

```css
p {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>This is the looooooo<img src="https://i.imgur.com/EgNYUyy.png" />ooong woooooooooooo<img src="https://i.imgur.com/EgNYUyy.png" />ooord</p>
```

Comment: I think that, if your client can't make html changes, you need some javascript here... Basically, search/replace desired section(s) and wrap words with images in new html controlled by css you can add in theme...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need nobr tag:

```css
p {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>This is the <nobr>looooooo<img src="https://i.imgur.com/EgNYUyy.png" />ooong</nobr> <nobr>woooooooooooo<img src="https://i.imgur.com/EgNYUyy.png" />ooord</nobr></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jas1rmwx/1/

I'm not sure how it's supported by the mobile browsers.

I don't see any other solution for text formatting. You can also make the words as inline-block and float left

UPDATE: inline-block solution:

```css
div {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nobr {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>This is the 
<div class="nobr">
 looooooo<img src="https://i.imgur.com/EgNYUyy.png" />ooong</div>
<div class="nobr">woooooooooooo<img src="https://i.imgur.com/EgNYUyy.png" />ooord</div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jas1rmwx/8/

Comment: yes, it is not standard and supported by all modern browsers, see also http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/nobr